# On average, set true on every fifth item, but not in even order

Tags: ruby

I have a collection with 100 items.

In an iteration I want to set an object attribute to `true` on 20 % of the items.

But I don't want the setting of true to occur evenly, i.e. on every fifth item.

It's even OK if not exactly 20 % gets `true`, as long as the setting is not set evenly.

Comment: Show us sample input data, and your expected output and code you've written attempting to do this please. Without it it seems like you're fishing for someone to write the code for you.

Comment: Are you generating that collection or loading it from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand):

```
def true_20_percent_of_the_time
  rand(5) == 0
end
```

Answer (score 3):

An inefficient but concise way of accomplishing this would be to shuffle your array, slice the first 20 elements, then set the attributes on them.

```
items.shuffle[0..19].each do |item|
  item.foo = true
end
```

If you care about efficiency, you may want to look into modifying the [Fisher Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

Comment: Shuffling 100 items should be quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating the array:

```
ary = Array.new(2, true) + Array.new(8, false)
ary # => [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
ary.shuffle # => [false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true]
```

That only uses 10 elements as an example, but I'm sure you can figure out how to adjust the count.

The above can be reduced to:

```
ary = (Array.new(2, true) + Array.new(8, false)).shuffle
# => [false, false, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, false]
```

And that can be reduced to:

```
ary = (([true] * 2) + ([false] * 8)).shuffle
# => [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, false]
```

If it's a pre-existing array:

```
ARRAY_SIZE = 10
ary = [false] * ARRAY_SIZE
```

Then you can slice it and reassign the number of `true` elements needed:

```
ary[0, (ARRAY_SIZE * 0.20).to_i] = [true] * (ARRAY_SIZE * 0.20)
ary # => [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

And then `shuffle` it:

```
ary.shuffle # => [true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the array

```
a = Array.new(21) { |i| i }
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3,..., 19, 20]
```

and you wanted to choose exactly

```
(a.size/5.0).round #=> 4
```

elements randomly. Then you could write:

```
@lucky_ones = [*(0...a.size)].sample((a.size/5.0).round)
  #=> [6, 12, 3, 9]

a.each_with_index do |e,i|
  puts "Wow! I've been selected. I'm #{e}" if @lucky_ones.include? i
end

Wow! I've been selected. I'm 3
Wow! I've been selected. I'm 6
Wow! I've been selected. I'm 9
Wow! I've been selected. I'm 12
```